# What is the best way to setup SSL certificates on a Multi Store installation?

Tags: configuration, multistore, server-setup

We currently have a client who has a multi store setup (3 websites) with 3 different URLS (.com,.fr,.ie). Each URL needed an SSL certificate and since an SSL certificate is bound to one IP we had to create several accounts on WHM and do some cpanel trickery (not ideal) to get the .fr and .ie to point to the .com directory while having an SSL associated with it.

This works for us *but* I am convinced there is a better way of doing this and I was wondering if the Magento community could enlighten me?

Comment: This is your web server issue. Please read my article for how to install [SSL](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-install-ssl-on-magento/) Certificate in your Magento store.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an IP per domain - you can use a single domain with a single certificate. This isn't using SNI - but SAN.

SAN is widely recognised and has 99.9% browser recognition.

So you could sign up for a SAN certificate (the Comodo Positive Multi-Domain is currently the cheapest) - and just add your other domains to the same certificate.

This would mean you only need a single account on cPanel (thus simplified permissions) - and you can keep editing/adding domains to the same certificate.

---

Otherwise, you could have multiple accounts, with multiple IPs (waste) - and maintain file permissions using ACLs/UMASK and sticky bits.

See http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/stop-magento-permissions-errors-permanently/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you usually do in your Magento installation - point all the store fronts to the same directory.

How you do this in your server or CPanel setup is not Magento related.

One side note: (even if slightly off-topic): You could avoid the need for different hosts in your webserver by using a multi-domain certificate. You could also avoid the need for different IPs by using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), but this might not be supported in legacy browsers.

Comment: Thanks @alex. Yes I am aware this seems more a server question but it's focused on Magento and I feel others would benefit from knowing something like this. I will have a chat with our sys admin about the multi-domain SSL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a web server issue. For instance basic apache wasn't capable of multiple SSL's on a single server with Virtual Hosts without multiple IPs... The trick is to understand your server config's capabilities. The best choice is an IP per each domain. One of the big reasons for this is its easier to manage multiple SSLs on a single host with VirtualHosts this way. The more important thing is for SEO having multiple domains on a single IP is --