# SSL Set-up advice with a Multi Website Magento

Tags: ssl, ce-1.9.2.0, apache

I have Magento website using multiple domains and I need an SSL for each of them has anyone already done this, their advice would be much appreciated.

1. I need to know if a Multi-Domain SSL be best or should I use SIN and purchase a regular SSL for each of them? and can this be done using the same IP
2. Also does anyone know if I need a Multi-Domain SSL or Multi-Domain OrganizationSSL to be PC/DSS compliant?

My set-up is:

- Centos 11.44
- Cpanel/WHM 6.6
- Apache
- Magento 1.9.2 CE

This question was some help: [What is the best way to setup SSL certificates on a Multi Store installation?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/831/what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-ssl-certificates-on-a-multi-store-installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. MultiDomain (SAN) SSL will work in all browsers on a single IP. Separate SSL certificates will require either SNI (unsupported in old browsers) or one IP-address per every SSL certificate. So, MultiDomain (SAN) SSL would be the best preferred solution assuming cost of IP-addresses renewal.
2. PCI DSS compliance is a result of implementation, it can be implemented with any valid SSL certificates.